# ORMLite with collection crash

Tags: java, android, ormlite

i have ormlite in android for persist my data.
Im having this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.firext.android/com.firext.android.activities.reportList.ReportListActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Foreign collection class com.firext.android.model.bbdd.DBQuestionsGroup for field 'questionsGroup' column-name does not contain a foreign field named 'questionsGroupsList' of class com.firext.android.model.bbdd.DBQuestions
```

My class its this;

```
    @DatabaseTable
    public class DBQuestionsGroup {

        @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "_id")
        private Long ID;
        @DatabaseField(columnName = "times")
        private int times;
        @DatabaseField(columnName = "idQuestionsGroup")
        private int idQuestionsGroup;
        @DatabaseField(columnName = "nameQuestionsGroup")
        private String nameQuestionsGroup;
        @ForeignCollectionField
        private Collection<DBQuestion> questionsGroupsList;

getters and setter


@DatabaseTable
public class DBQuestion {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "_id")
    private int ID;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "question")
    private String question;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "questionOrder")
    private int questionOrder;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true,foreignAutoCreate = true)
    private DBReplieType replyType;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "idQuestion")
    private int idQuestion;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh= true)
    private DBQuestionsGroup DBQuestion;
```

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set in the DBQuestionsGroup class the ForeingCollection in this way:

```
@ForeignCollectionField
private ForeignCollection<DBQuestion> questionsGroupsList;
```

This example could help you: https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/tree/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/examples/foreignCollection